# Bootsrap menu anchor only active after scrolling to middle of section

Tags: jquery, css

So i have a simple bootsrap page, where i use section ID's and then on the menu i target them. The problem is, when i click the menu, it goes to the correct section, but the menu link doesn't stay active. It only goes to active after i scroll a bit down.

This is annyoing when you have multiple section, because i click on for example the section 3, it goes to the section 3, but the menu active link is still the number 2, until i scroll a bit down on the section 3.

How can i fix this? Here is the website: https://salpoente.pt/convite-carta/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In file scrolling-nav.js change "54" to "1" on line 11.

```
$('a.js-scroll-trigger[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 1)
                }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo");
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```